# Java - Empty XML nodes

Tags: java, xml, csv

I am trying to create an XML file and when I am running this code, it is successfully creating XML file, but with empty nodes. My data is not parsing. This is the code -

```
public class xml {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>(5);

        File file = new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/data.csv");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
            // Root element
            Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("root");
            newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int line = 0;

            String text = null;
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "?", false);
                String[] rowValues = new String[st.countTokens()];
                int index = 0;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                    String next = st.nextToken();
                    rowValues[index++] = next;

                }

                // String[] rowValues = text.split(",");

                if (line == 0) { // Header row
                    for (String col : rowValues) {
                        headers.add(col);
                    }
                } else { // Data row
                    Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("row");
                    rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);

                    for (int col = 0; col < headers.size(); col++) {
                        String header = headers.get(col);
                        String value = null;

                        if (col < rowValues.length) {
                            value = rowValues[col];
                        } else {
                            // ?? Default value
                            value = " ";
                        }

                        System.out.println(header + " " + value);

                    }
                }
                line++;
            }

            try {

                TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
                aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                aTransformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

                Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
                Result result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/data.xml"));

                aTransformer.transform(src, result);
                System.out.println("File creation successfully!");

            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
                try {

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Anything I did wrong, not able to recognized the mistake.

**EDIT :-**

*Sample csv file and the output:-*

```
 Symbol,Open,High,Low,Last Traded Price,Change
"NIFTY 50","9,645.90","9,650.65","9,600.95","9,609.30","-5.70"
"RELIANCE","1,390.00","1,414.20","1,389.00","1,407.55","26.50"
"BPCL","647.70","665.00","645.95","660.10","10.75"
"ADANIPORTS","368.50","373.80","368.00","372.25","4.25"
"ONGC","159.50","161.75","159.35","160.80","1.70"
```

*output:-*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
    <row>"NIFTY 50","9,645.90","9,650.65","9,600.95","9,609.30","-5.70"</row>
    <row>"RELIANCE","1,390.00","1,414.20","1,389.00","1,407.55","26.50"</row>
    <row>"BPCL","647.70","665.00","645.95","660.10","10.75"</row>
    <row>"ADANIPORTS","368.50","373.80","368.00","372.25","4.25"</row>
    <row>"ONGC","159.50","161.75","159.35","160.80","1.70"</row>
</root>
```

Comment: Include a sample of your data

Comment: @SpaceBison I am now able to fetch the data but it is not correct. So do you want both CSV and output XML data ?

Comment: Any data relevant to the problem will certainly help

Comment: @SpaceBison I added the sample files . The header is not coming according to the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't user the variable `value`. So you should add a line, for example, `rowElement.setTextContent(value);` before the line `System.out.println(header + " " + value);`.

Comment: Thank You Sir,  I missed that out. Sir I have another problem regarding the output. Can I ask in d comment? It is small so I don't want to create another question for that.

Comment: No problem but I may not be able to answer your new question.

Comment: My XML output is not according to CSV file header .. It is like  <root><row>something......</row><row>something...</row></root> . The <row> must b header of CSV . Anything wrong I did? I guess I did it right.

Comment: You don't user the variable `header` too. Use it in the line: `Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("row");`.

Comment: I did and it coming in this way which is wrong :- <root><header>symbol,open,high,low..</header><row>...</row><row>....</row></root> ..the header tag must be according to each header file name and their children node will <row> accordingly.

Comment: If you have not got your expected result yet, please create a new question and write your code, CSV file, expected result.